# Giving different OSPF areas to a router

Tags: ospf

[image]

In the topology shown above each circle represent an area. Now I want to configure multi area OSPF on each router. So for the first router can I do like this:

```
router ospf 109
network 192.168.11.0 0.0.0.255 area 1
network 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
network 192.168.5.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
network 192.16.10.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
network 192.16.11.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
```

Is this correct method?

Comment: Just a comment to it - a router is called an ABR only when it has its interfaces in more than one area and out of those one area should be Area 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't tell which router you're configuring, but generally speaking, you're correct.

Your diagram is slightly misleading, because it shows routers belonging to a particular area.  The important thing to remember is that routers DO NOT belong in an area -- interfaces do.  If a router has interfaces in more than one area, then it's an ABR.  So the router configuration you've posted makes it an ABR.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to keep the routers out of the circle but forgot somehow. So if I exclude the routers from the center, then my method is correct, right?

Comment: Just make the center circle slightly smaller so that the one interface on all the routers is outside the circle, and the rest are inside.

Comment: why will I  leave those interfaces out from the circle and will I consider them when configuring the routers for OSPF?

Comment: The interfaces inside the circle are in area 0.  The others are in other areas.

Comment: I have posted a question regarding this matter, can you check it?